# \cite only returning link to bibliography and not author details

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I'm new to LaTeX, and I'm having some issued with `\cite`.

When I use `\cite`, the only thing that appears in the text is a number in squared-brackets with a link to the bibliography page. E.g: `\cite{Reference1}` --> [1]

Why isn't it printing out the author's name(s)?

```
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
```

---

```
\label{Bibliography}
\lhead{\emph{Bibliography}}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
```

Do I need to compile something else? Or am I missing some file?

Comment: This is the default behaviour of `\cite`: perhaps read the [`natbib` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/natbib).

Comment: If you want author-year citations, you should use the `authoryear` option instead of `numbers`

Comment: @egreg, thanks! That seems to solve my issue!

Comment: @JosephWright, thanks, I'll definitely have a look at it!

Comment: I have found that inserting `\usepackage{biblatex}` makes the key in `\cite{key}` show up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `natbib` package supports two main citation schemes: numeric and author-year. The default scheme is numeric (usually with the number in brackets like [3]) and can be specified with the (redundant) `numbers` option.

The author-year scheme, in which citations are like (Gauss, 1801), can be specified with the option `authoryear`. In this case other options such as `square`, `comma` and `sort&compress` should be omitted, as in parenthetical citations parentheses `(...)` rather than brackets `[...]` are more common.

Look at the package manual for the different citation commands for the author-year scheme: `\citep`, `\citet`, `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear`.

If you are just starting with LaTeX, I recommend to try `biblatex` rather than `natbib`. The former package is more recent and much more powerful. However one should be aware of the fact that some journals still don't support the more recent package.